# raspberry pi 7" screen automatically double clicking after single touch

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I'm using Raspian-Jessie (RaspberryPi 3 with official touch 7" screen) and for some reason when I do a single tap on the screen, it does a double click on the screen making it useless for applications using e.g. Kivy.

Is there a setting I need to change to make the touch just do one click? Or is this a bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't really seem like a programming question.

Comment: I think it is because there are configuration variables in various files which can be set to change the interface. There are also various potential package conflicts.